# Image Regonisation using java

Tags: java, image-processing

Is it possible to recognise the photo and identify what the photo has. For example If i have a `photo for the car. can i identify through the java code to find that photo has c`ar.

I google it but  i did not get any idea. I am new to the image recognition. please prvide idea of  how to start

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement some sort of AI to do that. Artificial Neural Networks, for example. This can be done with Java. Here is an example of such a project: http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html

Just be advised, if you're new to programming: this is some really advanced stuff. Like, rocket-science level stuff. So maybe you should perfect your coding skills and learn other things before you delve deeper into this.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) is a popular image recognition framework, and has recently opened support for standard java.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV works well on C++ and Python. It recently has bindings for desktop Java. But I think if you use OpenCV in Java, it will be painful as there are few documentations.

Also I think C++ is better for image recognition, it much faster!